# EditText not restoring state in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-fragments

I currently have a DialogFragment that has a couple of EditText widgets as part of  it's view.  When there is an orientation change happens the EditText widgets are not repopulated by the text that was in them.

I've looked through the saveInstanceState and the text is being persisted though the orientation  change.

DialogFragment:

```
    public final class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
    return v;
    }
}
```

an example EditText:

```
<EditText
android:text=""
android:id="@+id/loginUsername"
android:layout_width="180dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>
```

I am using the android compatibility package.

Comment: FWIW, here is an (elaborate) sample project that contains a `DialogFragment` that does not exhibit this problem: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Honeycomb/FeedFragments

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare I noticed that the AddFeedDialogFragment uses the onCreateDialog method and not the onCreateView method.  Perhaps thats the reason the data is properly restored.

Comment: You should inflate the view in onCreateDialog jut as you say. Are you the same author of the question? If so, did you try already?